# How do I extend ext4 partition using GParted?

Tags: gparted, partitioning, ext4, merge

I don't know how to extend partition `sda6` (ext4) with the unallocated space 265.54 gib

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `sda5`, `sda6`, and `sda7` are all within an extended partition; `sda3`.

You need to extend `sda3` to the right to take up all the space first.  In order to do this, you need to first boot off of a LiveUSB or DVD so that your partitions are not mounted.

[See here on how to make a Live USB.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu/152902)

Next, open `gparted`.  If not installed, install it with `sudo apt-get install gparted`.

Extend your `sda3` partition all the way to the left to take up the available space.  Note that it may be called `sdb3` or some other letter, so just ensure it's the right drive.

Your partitions 5-7 inside the extended partition will not move.

At this point, you can move `sda5` to the beginning of the drive (this will take time).  You will then have unallocated space to the right of `sda5`.

NOW you can extend your ext4 partition, `sda6` to take up the remaining space.